# Using @CrossOrigin annotation with JAX-RS (Jersey)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

Is it possible to annotate @CrossOrigin(Spring-MVC) with JAX-RS(Jersey) bassed annotations?

Answer (score 1):

You can create something like that by implementing `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` (see: [Filters](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9678)) with Annotation driven [Name binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9988) or [Dynamic binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e10061).

Here an `Annotation` you could use for Name or Dynamic binding:

```
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CrossOrigin {
    String origins();
}
```

Here is an incomplete example of a `DynamicFeature` implementation containing and registering the filter classes in dynamic manner:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.AnnotatedMethod;
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
public class CrossOriginDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    //check annotation, register filters if CrossOrigin is present (DynamicBinding)
    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceInfo resourceInfo, final FeatureContext configuration) {
        final AnnotatedMethod am = new AnnotatedMethod(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod());
        if (resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(CrossOrigin.class) != null) {
            configuration.register(CrossOriginFilter.class);
            configuration.register(ResponseCorsFilter.class);
        }
    }

    //this filter handles the request and checks the origin given
    @Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
    private static class CrossOriginFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        @Context
        private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

        @Context
        private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
            throws IOException {

            String origins = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getDeclaredAnnotation(CrossOrigin.class).origins();
            String originHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString("origin");

            //Maybe you want a different behaviour here. 
            //To prevent the execution of the annotated resource method 
            //if the origin of the request is not in the specified list, 
            //we break the execution with a 401.
            if (Arrays.asList(origins.split(",")).contains(originHeader)) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
    }

    //if the Request filter allows the access, 
    //the CORS header are added to the response here. 
    //There are other stackoverflow questions regarding this theme.
    public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
            //... add CORS header
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. Currently I have integrated OncePerRequestFilter for this because I was on Spring 3.0.5, but now I have upgraded it to 4.2.5. The problem is that when I use (at)CrossOrigin then I have to use (at)RestController and (at)RequestMapping but I have jersey (JAX-RS) dispatcher. Can I dispatch request to (at)RequestMapping by usinf Jersey dispatcher?
Your help will be appreciated :)

Comment: sorry i have no idea, maybe you ask another detaled question for this topic.